# Can I collapse tasks in a specific swimlane?

Tags: agile, jira

I would like to collapse tasks in my "DONE" swimlane, as this aggregates a lot of items and quickly forces every project to be very long.

This causes me to lose overview over other swimlanes, containing less items.

Is there a way to set a theme for each swimlane, so that tasks in the `DONE` swimlane only show their title and number?

Comment: What software are you talking about?

Comment: Atlassian Jira.

Answer (score 1):

We use quick filters to make the boards easier to navigate when there are a lot of issues. You could try creating a quick filter that hides the tasks in done status.

You can read additional information in these articles: [Configuring Quick Filters](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-quick-filters) and [JQL: The most flexible way to search JIRA](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14/).